# How to emit distinct values from MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I observed that `MutableLiveData` triggers `onChanged` of an observer even if the same object instance is provided to its `setValue` method.

```
//Fragment#onCreateView - scenario1
val newValue = "newValue"
mutableLiveData.setValue(newValue) //triggers observer
mutableLiveData.setValue(newValue) //triggers observer

//Fragment#onCreateView - scenario2
val newValue = "newValue"
mutableLiveData.postValue(newValue) //triggers observer
mutableLiveData.postValue(newValue) //does not trigger observer
```

Is there a way to avoid an observer be notified twice if the same or an equivalent instance is provided to `setValue()`/`postValue()`

I tried extending `MutableLiveData` but that did not work. I could be missing something here

```
class DistinctLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private var cached: T? = null

    @Synchronized override fun setValue(value: T) {
        if(value != cached) {
            cached = value
            super.setValue(value)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized override fun postValue(value: T) {
        if(value != cached) {
            cached = value
            super.postValue(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following magic trick to consume "items being the same":

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.distinctUntilChanged(): LiveData<T> = MediatorLiveData<T>().also { mediator ->
    mediator.addSource(this, object : Observer<T> {
        private var isInitialized = false
        private var previousValue: T? = null

        override fun onChanged(newValue: T?) {
            val wasInitialized = isInitialized
            if (!isInitialized) {
                isInitialized = true
            }
            if(!wasInitialized || newValue != previousValue) {
                previousValue = newValue
                mediator.postValue(newValue)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If you want to check referential equality, it's `!==`.

---

But it has since been added to `Transformations.distinctUntilChanged`.

Answer (score 48):

There is already in API : [Transformations.distinctUntilChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E))

> **distinctUntilChanged**
>
> ```
> public static LiveData<X> distinctUntilChanged (LiveData<X> source)
> ```
>
> Creates a new [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.html) object does not emit a value until the source
>   LiveData value has been changed. The value is considered changed if
>   `equals()` yields `false`.
>
> <<snip remainder>>

Comment: Since this got flagged as a possible link-only answer, I excerpted a bit of the documentation.

Comment: Worth mentioning, that `Transformations.distingUntilChanged()` is available earliest in Ver 2.1.0 which is not yet a stable release!
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.1.0-alpha01

Comment: update: It is now in the stable release. safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

If we talk about `MutableLiveData`, you can create a class and override setValue and then only call through super if `new value != old value`

```
class DistinctUntilChangedMutableLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    override fun setValue(value: T?) {
        if (value != this.value) {
            super.setValue(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure why this did not get more upvotes, seems the simplest and cleanest way imo.

Comment: Yes, you should know how equality works, does not make the answer wrong though.

Comment: @bastami82: Please stop changing my answer. Correct my typos, add some formatting, that's fine, for anything else, write your own answer.

Comment: just tried to be helpful as my suggested changes did NOT change the essence of your answer, I could have written my own answer you are right, but I thought given all credit to your answer, sadly you did not appreciate the effort (by the way this is how code evolves). In my view suggested changes made it clearer, I only thought this is a good answer and need a bit of polishing, disappointed you did not like it but I respect your decision.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have quite complex objects which I have to compare by some fields. For this I've changed EpicPandaForce's answer:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.distinctUntilChanged(compare: T?.(T?) -> Boolean = { this == it }): LiveData<T> = MediatorLiveData<T>().also { mediator ->
    mediator.addSource(this) { newValue ->
        if(!newValue.compare(value)) {
            mediator.postValue(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

By default it uses standard `equals` method, but if you need - you can change distinction logic

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the **MediatorLiveData**, i just wrapper my observer, and record and compare it. it work well in my livedata-Bus

```
class DiffObserver<X>(var observer: Observer<X>) : Observer<X>{

    var mFirstTime = true
    var previousValue : X? = null

    override fun onChanged(currentValue: X?) {
        if (mFirstTime || (previousValue == null && currentValue != null) ||
                (previousValue != null && currentValue == null) ||
                previousValue?.equals(currentValue) != true) {
            mFirstTime = false
            observer.onChanged(currentValue)
        } 
        previousValue = currentValue
    }

}
```